# Spring Data: Enumeration and Repository issue

Tags: spring, enums, spring-data

I am using Spring Data and Repositories. I created an Entity with a enum type field, which I declared @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING), but I am forced to create a method getAuthority returning a String.

```
@Entity
@Configurable
public class BaseAuthority implements GrantedAuthority {

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(unique = true)
    private AuthorityType authority;

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return authority.toString();
    }

}
```

The enum is as follow:

```
public enum AuthorityType {
REGISTEREDUSER, ADMINISTRATOR;
}
```

In the repository for the entity, I created an operation to find by authority type:

```
@Repository
public interface BaseAuthorityRepository extends JpaRepository<BaseAuthority, Long> {

    BaseAuthority findByAuthority(AuthorityType authority);

}
```

However, I get a warning:

```
Parameter type (AuthorityType) does not match domain class 
property definition (String). BaseAuthorityRepository.java
```

I used to have the operation receiving a String rather than AuthorityType, but that generates a runtime exception. 
I could change the name of the field authority to authorityType, but I don't like that.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I remove the warning?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I guess you have to rename the field, but you can do it in an transparent way:

```
@Entity
public class BaseAuthority implements GrantedAuthority {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(unique = true, name = "authority")
    private AuthorityType authorityType;

    AuthorityType getAuthorityType() {
        return authorityType;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return authorityType.toString();
    }
}
```

and change your repository to

```
@Repository
public interface BaseAuthorityRepository extends JpaRepository<BaseAuthority, Long> {

    BaseAuthority findByAuthorityType(AuthorityType authority); 
}
```

Comment: I think it would be easier to leave the field as enum and just change the column name. Enum will be easier to use in code.