# Using enum to filter status

Tags: spring-boot, enums, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Hi I have spring service and in the repository I'm trying to filter by enum

`List<Organization> findAllByStatus(StatusType type);`

and for some reason this enum param is not passed to sql query.

I see `where organizati0_.status=?` in SQL but no parameters are passed.

Any idea what can be a reason?

Enum:

```
public enum StatusType {
  ACTIVE,
  TO_BE_DELETED,
  @Deprecated IN_ACTIVE
}
```

Service:

```
public List<Organization> getAllOrganizations() {
        return Lists.newArrayList(organizationRepository.findAllByStatus(StatusType.TO_BE_DELETED));
}
```

Comment: Are you sure they are not being passed? Perhaps parameters are just hidden behind question mark.

Comment: yes when I'm adding the second param I see only second one: ```Hibernate: select ...  from organization organizati0_ where organizati0_.status=? and organizati0_.name=?
2019-10-23 16:34:31.003 TRACE 19884 --- [0.1-9090-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [test]```

Comment: Could you post your model. Im interested in the part where you defined the column for that enum

Comment: My guess, use ```@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)``` in the column definition of your entity class.

Comment: ```public class Organization extends AbstractBaseEntity implements BaseEntity```

Comment: ```@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractBaseEntity```

```@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column
private StatusType status;```

Comment: BaseEntity interfece:

```StatusType getStatus();

void setStatus(StatusType status)```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import com.example.demo.jobs.CustomQueryParamMethodInterceptor;

import org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.mapping.context.MappingContext;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.RepositoryInformation;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryProxyPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryFactoryBeanSupport;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

public class MyJpaRepositoryFactoryBean<T extends Repository<S, ID>, S, ID extends Serializable>
        extends TransactionalRepositoryFactoryBeanSupport<T, S, ID> {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private static final CustomQueryParamMethodInterceptor interceptor = new CustomQueryParamMethodInterceptor();
    /**
     * Creates a new {@link JpaRepositoryFactoryBean} for the given repository interface.
     *
     * @param repositoryInterface must not be {@literal null}.
     */
    public MyJpaRepositoryFactoryBean(Class<? extends T> repositoryInterface) {
        super(repositoryInterface);
    }

    /**
     * The {@link EntityManager} to be used.
     *
     * @param entityManager the entityManager to set
     */
    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport#setMappingContext(org.springframework.data.mapping.context.MappingContext)
     */
    @Override
    public void setMappingContext(MappingContext<?, ?> mappingContext) {
        super.setMappingContext(mappingContext);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see org.springframework.data.repository.support.
     * TransactionalRepositoryFactoryBeanSupport#doCreateRepositoryFactory()
     */
    @Override
    protected RepositoryFactorySupport doCreateRepositoryFactory() {
        RepositoryFactorySupport support = createRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
        support.addRepositoryProxyPostProcessor(new RepositoryProxyPostProcessor() {
            @Override
            public void postProcess(ProxyFactory factory, RepositoryInformation repositoryInformation) {
                factory.addAdvice(interceptor);
            }
        });
        return support;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a {@link RepositoryFactorySupport}.
     *
     * @param entityManager
     * @return
     */
    protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
        return new JpaRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see
     * org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean#afterPropertiesSet()
     */
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {

        Assert.notNull(entityManager, "EntityManager must not be null!");
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }
}
```

and then add annotation to your spring application class

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = MyJpaRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
```

and the create a method interceptor to convert the Enum Parameter to a specific type

```
import java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import com.example.demo.dto.ParamWrapper;
import com.example.demo.dto.StatusType;
import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor;
import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation;

import org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation;

public class CustomQueryParamMethodInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        if (invocation instanceof ReflectiveMethodInvocation) {
            ReflectiveMethodInvocation rmi = (ReflectiveMethodInvocation)invocation;
            Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
            if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
                Object[] newArgs = new Object[args.length];
                for (int i=0 ;i<args.length; i++) {
                    if (args[i] instanceof ParamWrapper) {
                        ParamWrapper p = (ParamWrapper)args[i];
                        newArgs[i] = p.getValue();
                    } else {
                        newArgs[i] = args[i];
                    }
                }
                rmi.setArguments(newArgs);
            }
        }
        return invocation.proceed();
    }
}
```

the ParamWrapper is a generic type which your enum should implement

```
public interface ParamWrapper<T> {
    T getValue();
}
```

then your enum should change like this

```
public enum StatusType implements ParamWrapper<Integer> {
    ACTIVE,
    TO_BE_DELETED,
    @Deprecated IN_ACTIVE;

    @Override
    public Integer getValue() {
        //you should determine your value
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25161241/spring-data-enumeration-and-repository-issue it should be working with simply enum setup. Do I really need to wrap my enum?

Comment: i think my solution is more flexible that you can pass any enum or even any custom types to your jpa repository method as a parameter, but the \@Enumerated annotation should be used in the \@Entity object